# What is the best practice for caching user data in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, session-variables

When a user signs in to my website, I want cache some data like email, confirmation status, mobile confirmation status, etc. Because I don't want fetch this data in each page request. The requirement is that the user must confirm email and mobile before do anything.
I am using code like this:

```
public static class CachedData
{
    public static bool IsEmailConfirmed
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsEmailConfirmed"] == null)
                Initialize();
            return Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session["IsEmailConfirmed"]);
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["IsEmailConfirmed"] = value;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsMobileConfirmed
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["IsMobileConfirmed"] == null)
                Initialize();
            return Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Session["IsMobileConfirmed"]);
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["IsMobileConfirmed"] = value;
        }
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        UserAccount currentUser = UserAccount.GetUser();
        if (currentUser == null)
            return;

        IsEmailConfirmed = currentUser.EmailConfirmed;
        IsMobileConfirmed = currentUser.MobileConfirmed;   
    }
}
```

I have `PageBase` class that all page classes drive from it. I am using class `CachedData` in `PageBase` class:

```
public class PageBase : Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (authentication.Required && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !IsPostBack)
        {
            if (CachedData.HasProfile && (!CachedData.IsEmailConfirmed || !CachedData.IsMobileConfirmed) && !Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().EndsWith("settings.aspx"))
                Response.Redirect("/settings-page", true);
        }
    }
}
```

May be it is strange, but this code, sometimes work wrong and redirect to setting page for user confirmed email and mobile.
Is there any better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if this is your logic, you should create an object `UserInfo`. Something like this:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailConfirmed {get; set; }
    public bool IsMobileConfirmed {get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Then set this object into session. Now! when any operation on user record are performed in your BLL, you should re-populate new Instance of `UserInfo` and replace old one in the session. This way your user info will be up to day and will always work.

But your problem may coming from the fact that you use a web farm and your sessions are not synchronized. You need to use a sticky session so each request from the unique user is processed on the same server. Right now there is thing called `App Fabric`. It is caching on steroids. It can find an item in cache on another server.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store different fields of your object in the different session names.
If you do need to use sessions, you can store the whole user object in your session.

The choice where to store the data depands on the requirements (including how critical are the data and the requirements for such the things as IIS reset) and what and why you really have to store.
Depending on the answers you could store your data either in a session or in a viewstate or in cache or in application.
You can also look at the cache because it provides some nice features like automatic update, triggering, etc.